# Fundamental group of $S^1 \cup \{(x,y) : xy=0 \}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Could someone help me to calculate the foundamental group of $S^1 \cup \{(x,y) : xy=0 \}$ without using Seifert Van Kampen? Thanks.

Comment: Dear Paula, could you please let us know what have you tried so far? For example, have you thought about finding a space that is homotopy equivalent to your space, which you know how to compute the fundamental group for?

Comment: And is the $S^1$ a unit circle in the $(x,y)$ plane?

Comment: Yes, is  a unit circle. I know that the foundamental group of S1 is isomorphic to Z. But, nothing more.

Comment: Imagine that your space is made of wet clay. Can you think of any ways of shrinking parts of your space to turn it into something simpler?

Comment: {x*y=0}={x=0}U{y=0} , and I think that the fundamental group of this lines is the trivial fundamental group, but it's true?

Comment: That's right. One way to show this is to realise that $\{ x = 0 \} \cup \{ y = 0 \}$ deformation retracts onto the origin. Intuitively, it's possible to shrink $\{ x = 0 \} \cup \{ y = 0 \}$ to a point if it is made of clay. Now, for your example, we can do the same for the "outer rays", e.g. $\{ (x,0) : x \in [1,\infty) \}$.

Comment: Good, I understand you. But, how can I prove that?

Comment: For your baby example of $X = \{ x = 0 \} \cup \{ y = 0 \}$, we need to show that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y = \{(0,0) \}$. This will prove that $\pi_1 (X) = \pi_1 (Y)$. To do this, we just need to write down a pair of maps $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g $ is homotopic to $id_X$ and $g \circ f $ is homotopy to $id_Y$. Let's define $f$ to send every point in $X$ to $(0,0)\in Y$, and define $g$ to send $(0,0) \in Y$ to $(0,0)\in X$. Then $g \circ f$ maps every point in $X$ to $(0,0)$. A homotopy from $g \circ f$ to $id_X$ is given by $(t,(x,y)) \mapsto (tx,ty)$.

Comment: it's enough to proof that?

Comment: If two spaces are homotopy equivalent, then they have the same fundamental group.

Comment: Let me give you one more baby example. Suppose we want to find the fundamental group of $X = S^1 \cup \{(x,y): x \in [-1,1] \}$. If this space is made of clay, then we could shrink the $\{(x,y): x \in [-1,1] \}$ to a point. After shrinking, the space $X$ becomes the space $Y = S^1 \vee S^1$ (i.e. two circles joined at a single point). To be more rigorous, $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent to each other. Therefore, the fundamental group of $X$ is the same as the fundamental group of $Y$, which is the free group generated by two elements.

Comment: (Okay, technically, your textbook probably used van Kampen to get the fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1$, but I'll assume that you're allowed to quote this result for the exercise you're working on, otherwise the problem would be horrendous!)

Comment: Okey, I understood you. My previous question is that  your explanation is enough to proof that the spaces are homotopy equivalent